# How do I get the current product id into wishlist.phtml in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, product, wishlist, id

Here is My Block.php file

> app/code/Smartwave/Porto/Block/Catalog/Product/View/AddTo/Wishlist.php

```
namespace Smartwave\Porto\Block\Catalog\Product\View\AddTo;

/**
 * Product view wishlist block
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.1.1
 */
class Wishlist extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
{
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct(  
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry

    )
    {      
        $this->registry = $registry;

    }

 .
 .
 .
 .
 .


    public function getProductIdWishlist(){

         $currentProduct=$this->registry->registry('current_product');
       return $currentProduct->getCurrentProduct(); 
    }
}
```

my .phtml file

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Wishlist/templates/catalog/product/view/addto/wishlist.


<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\View\AddTo\Wishlist $block */
?>
<?php if ($block->isWishListAllowed()) : ?>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)"
       class="action towishlist"
       data-pdtId="<?php echo $block->getProductIdWishlist();?>"
       data-action="add-to-wishlist"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')) ?></span></a>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "body": {
            "addToWishlist": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getWishlistOptionsJson() ?>
        }
    }
</script>
```

i need to print current product id inside 'data-pdtId' tag there is any way to print id without using object manager ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return wrong value in your block function. Use this below code in your function :

```
public function getProductIdWishlist(){
    $currentProduct = $this->registry->registry('current_product');
    return $currentProduct->getId(); 
}
```

Or try this below code also :

```
public function getProductIdWishlist(){
    $currentProduct = $this->registry->registry('product');
    return $currentProduct->getId(); 
}
```

If you extends `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` class in your block. Then, you can also use this below code :

```
$this->getProduct()->getId();
```

---

**Override block file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\View\AddTo\Wishlist" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Catalog\Product\View\AddTo\Wishlist"/>
</config>
```

Comment: already try this way , but it returns empty

Comment: Try to pass $currentProduct->getName(); You get value or not?

Comment: @ShafeelSha Check my updated answer.

Comment: nothing happen !

Comment: Did you used my updated answer?

Comment: yes ' i'm using both answers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96599/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-shafeel-sha).

Comment: Okay. Let me check that.

Answer (score 0):

In your block file use get Id ,

```
namespace Smartwave\Porto\Block\Catalog\Product\View\AddTo;

class Wishlist extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
{
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct(  
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {      
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function getProductIdWishlist(){

       $currentProduct=$this->registry->registry('current_product');
       return $currentProduct->getId(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can get `product id` like this

```
$product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');//get current product                    
$productId = $product->getId();
```

> You're extending `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` you can get `product_id` like this

```
$product = $this->getProduct();
return $product->getId();
```

or

```
$this->getProductId();
```